# Create a recursive function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to call a function from itself but it gives me the error

> 'CalculateHoursBetweenDates' is not a recognized built-in function name.

I know this is because I haven't created the function but I am calling it from inside the function itself.

This is my code:

```
create function CalculateHoursBetweenDates
     (@start varchar(50), 
      @end varchar(50), 
      @days int = 0) 
returns int
as 
begin
    declare @dayDiff int = DATEDIFF(d, @start, @end) + DATEPART(dw, @start)

    if(@dayDiff > 6) 
    begin
        set @days = @days + (DATEPART(dw, @start) -7)
        set @start = DATEADD(d, 7 - (datepart(dw, @start) - 2), @start)
        return CalculateHoursBetweenDates(@start, @end, @days)
    end 

    return @days + DATEDIFF(d, @start, @end)
end
```

Am I calling it the wrong way or what? Do I have to create an empty function first? I don't get it

Comment: Try prefixing it with `dbo.`:  `dbo.CalculateHoursBetweenDates`

Comment: ok, that worked. Can you explain me why it needs the schema to be specified for this?

Comment: @TylerRoper whoops indeed, it matters. Retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you need schema prefix :

```
select <scheme>.CalculateHoursBetweenDates (. . . .)
```

However, the default schema name is `dbo`